# Fit a circle with pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning

How to construct a network such that the input is a coordinate on a cross-section circle and the output is the sum of the squares of that coordinate.inputs=[x,y,1]，outputs=[square(x)+square(y)]

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
import torch.optim 
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
features = torch.tensor([[8.3572,-11.3008,1],[6.2795,-12.5886,1],[4.0056,-13.4958,1]
                         ,[1.6219,-13.9933,1],[-0.8157,-14.0706,1],[-3.2280,-13.7250,1]
                         ,[-5.5392,-12.9598,1],[-7.6952,-11.8073,1],[-9.6076,-10.3035,1],
                         [-11.2532,-8.4668,1],[-12.5568,-6.3425,1],[-13.4558,-4.0691,1],
                         [-13.9484,-1.7293,1],[-14.0218,0.7224,1],[-13.6791,3.1211,1],
                         [-12.9064,5.4561,1],[-11.7489,7.6081,1],[-10.2251,9.5447,1],
                         [5.4804,12.8044,1],[7.6332,11.6543,1],[9.5543,10.1454,1],
                         [11.1890,8.3117,1],[12.4705,6.2460,1],[13.3815,3.9556,1],
                         [13.8733,1.5884,1],[13.9509,-0.8663,1],[13.6014,-3.2793,1],
                         [12.8572,-5.5526,1],[11.7042,-7.7191,1],[10.1761,-9.6745,1],
                         [-8.4301,11.1605,1],[-6.3228,12.4433,1],[-4.0701,13.3401,1],
                         [-1.6816,13.8352,1],[0.7599,13.9117,1],[3.1672,13.5653,1]]).to(device)
labels = []
for i in range(features.shape[0]):
    label=(features[i][0])**2+(features[i][1])**2
    labels.append(label)
labels = torch.tensor(labels).to(device)
num_input ,num_hidden,num_output = 3,64,1
net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(num_input,num_hidden),
    nn.Linear(num_hidden,num_output)
).to(device)

def init_weights(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Linear:
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight)

net.apply(init_weights)

def init_bias(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Linear:
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.bias)

loss = nn.MSELoss()


num_epochs = 10
batch_size = 6
lr=0.001
trainer = torch.optim.RAdam(net.parameters(),lr=lr)
dataset = TensorDataset(features,labels)
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)

for i in range (num_epochs):
    for X,y in data_loader:
        y_hat = net(X)
        l = loss(y_hat,y.reshape(y_hat.shape))
        trainer.zero_grad()
        l.backward()
        trainer.step()
    with torch.no_grad():
        print(l.item())
```

I made a network with one hidden layer, but it has very high losses and is almost impossible to fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve the convergence of your code, you can do these suggestions:

- Scale you input data into a similar range using min-max scaling or standardization:

```
mean = features[:,:2].mean(dim=0)
std = features[:,:2].std(dim=0)
features[:,:2] = (features[:,:2] - mean) / std
```

- Increase `num_epochs`:

```
num_epochs = 100
```

- Change `batch_size`:

```
batch_size = 2
```

I run your code with the above changes, and it converges.